# How to use enzyme to test component with asyn lifecircle function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, enzyme, jestjs

I'm using jest and enzyme to test my component. And in this component, I will request data in componentDidMount, and then it will render view with the data.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  async componentDidMount() {
    const data = await getData(); // send a request to server to get data

    this.setState({
      name: data.name,
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>{this.state.name}</div>
    )
  }
}
```

It is a very simple component, just only use async function in componentDidMount, and get data width a async way, not callback. But, I don't know how to test this component.

I'd like write test code like this

```
it('render', async () => {
  const container = mount(
    <App />  
  );  

  const instance = container.instance();
  console.log(instanct.state.name); // of course, state.name is undefined, but I want in this place, the state.name can be 'qyt'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a [demo project on Github here](https://github.com/newyork-anthonyng/async-await-test).

The solution I went with was to mock the `getData` module:

```
let mockPromise;
jest.mock("./getData", () => {
  return jest.fn(() => {
    mockPromise = Promise.resolve({ name: "Spider man" });
    return mockPromise;
  });
});
```

Then I returned the `mockPromise` in my test. Jest will wait for the promise to resolve before completing the test.

```
it("renders without crashing", () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<App />);

  return mockPromise.then((a) => {
    wrapper.update();

    expect(wrapper.html()).toEqual(`<h1>Name: Spider man</h1>`);
  });
});
```

Comment: what's the diffenerence between your normal function 'getData' and jest mock function 'getData'. These two function are both promise

Comment: With the mocked `getData` function, I'm setting a variable, `mockPromise`, to equal the returned promise.

By doing this, I can return `mockPromise` in my test. If I hadn't mocked `getData`, I wouldn't have access to the promise returned by `getData`.